# composer create-project without the need to have internet access

Tags: laravel, composer-php

From my understanding, the following command will go to internet to download some files (such as the https://packageist.org/packages.json).

> composer create-project laravel/laravel MyProject --prefer-dist

Is it possible to download all the required files so that the above command do not require internet access? (meaning that it will use local drive for to create the project.)

Answer (score 2):

You can [setup local mirror](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-a-local-mirror-for-composer-packages-with-satis--net-36726) for any packages you want. Alternatively, you could just create batch script (shell script) which would copy whole project from any local computer or from local directory on the same machine.

```
"repositories": [
     {
         "type": "composer",
         "url": "http://localhost:4680"
     }
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't require internet connection only if requested package is available in your local cache.

Despite of that, offline mode is something that was requested some time ago.
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2244

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **repositories** key in your composer.json file -

```
{
    "name": "atefth/project",
    "description": "Test project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Atef Haque",
            "email": "atefth@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "../package"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "atefth/package": "*"
    }
}
```

> You need to download all your dependencies inside the **../package** directory